# How to get the coordinates after a mouse click?

Tags: python, click, coordinates, pywin32

I was using the following code to get the coordinates of a point after a  mouse click (keep in mind I was clicking on a random point on the screen, not on a figure):

```
import win32api
posvals = [[],[]]
x = 0
state_left = win32api.GetKeyState(0x01)
while x<2:
    a = win32api.GetKeyState(0x01)    

    if a != state_left:
        state_left = a
        print(a)
        if a >= 0:
            print('button down')
            z,y = win32api.GetCursorPos()
            posvals[x] = [z,y]

            print(z,y)
            x += 1
    time.sleep(.001)
print(posvals)
```

Here I saved the coordinates in `posvals`, and the `while` loop is there because I only wanted to record 2 clicks. I got and tweaked this code from another question on stackoverflow, but I'm not sure which one.

My current problem is that I'm using a Linux computer and the win32api module (its official name is pywin32) won't work since it is only for windows. 
How can I adjust (or completely restart) my code?

Answer (score 1):

So there is no easy way to port the code to linux, unless you run in wrapped with WineLib or equivalent wrapper software. One such explanation of this practice is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14162669/9722265).

You could try other mouse position packages like [PyMouse](https://pypi.org/project/PyMouse/). This might be a better option. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25848951/python-get-mouse-x-y-position-on-click) also has some good examples of other more agnostic package options for python mouse coordinates.